# Typescript string prototype show error in webstorm IDE

Tags: typescript, prototype, webstorm

I defined the following format function to String.
This works OK, but the problem is that webstorm is marking the "String.prototype.format" in red.
How can I suppress the error?

```
interface String {
    format(variables:Array<string>):string
}

String.prototype.format = (variables:Array<string>):string => {
    return this.replace(/%(\d+)/g, function(_,m) {
        return variables[--m];
    });
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, I ended up with this:

```
interface String {
    format(variables:Array<string>):string
}

if (!String.hasOwnProperty("format")) {
    String.prototype["format"] = function (variables:Array<string>) : string   {
        return this.replace(/%(\d+)/g, function(_,m) {
            return variables[--m];
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. See [WEB-14302](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14302#comment=27-978747)

The problem should be fixed in the next WebStorm 11 EAP.